# C# incorrect dir when trying to save Chart

Tags: c#, image, charts, system.io.file, system.io.directory

I hope you can help me with this, I'm trying to generate an image from a chart, first I use:

```
public void generateDIR()
{
    DocumentsDIR = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    bool flag=true;
    int counter = 0;
    while (flag)
    {
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine(counter);
        string dateforDir = "_"+DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() + "_"+ DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        ReportDIR = DocumentsDIR + "/SisDatCal_Reports/Report_"+counter.ToString()+dateforDir+ "/";
        bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(ReportDIR);
        if (!exists)
        {
            ReportPlotsDIR = ReportDIR + "Plots/";
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ReportDIR);
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ReportPlotsDIR);
            flag = false;
        }     
     }
}
```

to get the directory generated "ReportPlotsDir" in which I want to save the image, then I use the next code to generate the image of the chart "chartVolts":

```
String ChartVName = ReportPlotsDIR + "IMG_ChartVolts.png";
chartVolts.SaveImage(ChartVName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

this works fine and there is no error shown during the execution of the program, but, when I go to my folders and search for "IMG_ChartVolts.png" it is saved in the "Bin\Debug" folder of the solution and not in the "ReportPlotsDIR". Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  What is the value of `ReportPlotsDIR`?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but if this is running on Windows, paths are separated by back slashes "\" not forward slashes "/".  Use `Path.Combine` and it will be taken care of for you.

Comment: You need to debug.  View the values of your variables while debugging. You will see what is not what you think it should be, and when.  This is a basic and *extremely* important skill needed by developers.  If you don't know how, stop everything you have ever thought about doing and read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Put a debug point and see the value of `ReportDIR`, you will notice that you need to use back slash rather than forward slash, but it is better to use Path.Combine like:

```
ReportDIR = Path.Combine(DocumentsDIR, "SisDatCal_Reports\\Report_" + counter + dateforDir + "\\");
```

Apart from that, for formatting Date you can use :

```
string dateforDir = DateTime.Now.ToString("_MM_dddd_yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I implemented this but the problem is still happening

Comment: Replace `ReportPlotsDIR = ReportDIR + "Plots/";` with `ReportPlotsDIR = Path.Combine(ReportDIR, "Plots\\");` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, there was an error in the execution order and not in the path generation, I didn't see it until I debug it properly. If anyone need it, the code post in the question works perfect.